# How to create new local branch in Git

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am working on a project which I cloned from a remote repository hosted on [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab). I made some changes to the project, but I didn’t create any branch and want to now start work on some other new features, but without first pushing my existing work to the remote repository.

I might discard the changes in the new feature or might need to push both the new feature as well as the earlier changes to the remote repository, at a later stage.

From what I know about Git, I think I need to create a new local branch, which I can do using `git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME`. Is this the correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  When I use this command, it creates a new branch. How do I switch back and forth between working on this new branch and the earlier one?

Comment: This is #2 in a search engine result for "`git create new branch`"... Where is the canonical question?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You switch back and forth between branches using `git checkout <branch name>`.

And yes, `git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME` is the correct way to create a new branch and switching to it. At the same time, the command you used is a shorthand to `git branch <branch name>` and `git checkout <branch name>`.

Comment: So I have to first give a branch name to my existing changes using `git branch OLD_CHANGES`, then create a branch for new features and switch to it using `git -b NEW_FEATURES`. Then when I am ready to push `OLD_CHANGES` to remote or again make some changes to it, use `git checkout OLD_CHANGES`? Is this correct?

Comment: well if you already committed your changes to say master branch then you'll have to resort to some other methods. this might [help](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) with regard to branching and switching to it

Comment: I just pulled from the remote repo and made many changes in it so far, havent done any committing so far using any GUI or command. So can I go ahead with the commands I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: yeah, you can go ahead create a branch make your changes to it and push it. here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6b6B9oN4Vg) if you are new to git.